# Get data from controller action to jquery datatable

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, datatables

I'm trying to get some data from controller action in JSON format then send it to DataTables using AJAX, the data is shown but when I search or sort the data disappears and "no data found" message displayed, also there's no longer any pages it's just one long table.

**HTML table:**

```
<table id="demoGrid" class="table  table table-hover dt-responsive nowrap" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr class="styleHeaderTab">
            <th class="th-sm">
                Matricule
            </th>
            <th class="th-sm">
                Intitulé
            </th>
            <th class="th-sm">
                Nombre de compte
            </th>
            <th class="">
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="chargeHolder"></tbody>
</table>
```

**Script:**

```
$(document).ready(() => getActif());
$('#demoGrid').dataTable({
        "language": {
            "search": "Rechercher",
            "lengthMenu": "Afficher _MENU_ chargés par page",
            "info": "Page: _PAGE_ / _PAGES_",
            "paginate": {
                "next": "Suivante",
                "previous": "Précédente"
            }
        }
    });
function getActif() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/ChargeAffaire/GetActif',
            method: 'get',
            dataType: 'json',
            error: (err) => console.log(err),
            success: (res) => {
                let s="";
                for (let i=0;i<res.length;i++) {
                    s +=`<tr>
                            <td>${res[i].matricule}</td>
                            <td>${res[i].intitule}</td>
                            <td> 59</td>
                            <td id="linkContainer">
                                <a class="cls no-href" id="detail" onclick="update_url('consulter/${res[i].id}')" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">consulter</a>
                                <br/>
                                <a class="no-href" id="conge" onclick="updateConge(${res[i].id})" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dateMission">Ajouter un congé</a>
                                <br/>
                                <a class="no-href" id="ajout"  onclick="updateAction(${res[i].id})" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ajoutModal">Ajouter un compte</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>`;
                }
                $("#chargeHolder").html(s);
                $(".no-href").css({"cursor":"pointer","color":"#077bb1"});
                $(".no-href").parent().css("text-align","center");
            }
        });
    }
```

**Controller's action:**

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult GetActif()
        {
            var list = ListCharges.list.FindAll(x => x.conge.etat == "Actif");
            return Json(list);
        }
```

Comment: why did you not use the ajax option in the DataTable object? https://www.datatables.net/manual/ajax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using *external* jQuery methods, like `$.ajax()`, `$.post()`, `$.get()` and such to populate DataTable is **extremely** bad practice as you end up coping with the mess of workarounds to make your data get loaded into table where and when it is necessary. Instead, I suggest to employ [`ajax`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) option.

Another bad choice is cooking up table body HTML manually. DataTables can perfectly do that for you, should you just point to column data source with [`columns`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns) / [`columnDefs`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs) options.

In order to get some table column rendered as an arbitrary HTML there is another option [`columns.render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render).

And, finally, you may append HTML attributes to your cell using [`columns.createdCell`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.createdCell) option.

So, your complete jQuery code might look something, like:

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    $('#demoGrid').dataTable({
        ajax: {
            url: '/ChargeAffaire/GetActif'
        },
        language: {
            search: "Rechercher",
            lengthMenu: "Afficher _MENU_ chargés par page",
            info: "Page: _PAGE_ / _PAGES_",
            paginate: {
                next: "Suivante",
                previous: "Précédente"
            }
        },
        columns: [
            {title: 'Matricule', data: 'matricule'},
            {title: 'Intitulé', data: 'intitule'},
            {title: 'Nombre de compte', data: () => ' 59'},
            {
                title: '', 
                data: rowData => `
                    <a class="cls no-href" id="detail" onclick="update_url('consulter/rowData.id')" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">consulter</a>
                    <br/>
                    <a class="no-href" id="conge" onclick="updateConge(rowData.id)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dateMission">Ajouter un congé</a>
                    <br/>
                    <a class="no-href" id="ajout"  onclick="updateAction(rowData.id)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ajoutModal">Ajouter un compte</a>`,
                createdCell: td => $(td).attr('id', 'linkContainer')
            }
        ],
        //append custom classes for the first 3 <th> and id attribute to <tbody>
        renderCallback: function(){
            this.api().columns().every(function(){
                if(this.index() < 3) $(this.header()).addClass('th-sm');
            });
            $('#demoGrid tbody').attr('id', 'chargeHolder');
        }
    });
});
```

While your HTML may be as simple, as:

```
<table id="demoGrid" class="table  table table-hover dt-responsive nowrap" width="100%" cellspacing="0"></table>
```

And your CSS I'd recommend to put into separate file.

In order to reload your data when necessary you may simply invoke [`ajax.reload()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()) method, benefiting from [`ajax.data`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data) option as a callback to manipulate parameters sent to the backend script, if needed.

Answer (score -1):

controller:

```
[HttpGet] public ActionResult GetActif(){
                total = list.Count,
                rows = (from u in list
                        select new
                        {


                            id = u.Id,
                            Name = u.sName,



                        }).ToArray()
            };

     return JsonData;
}
```

for script:

```
dataType: 'json',
success: function (result) {
    $("#action").text("");
    var html = '';$.each(result.rows, function (key, item) {
        html += '<tr>';
        html += '<td class="text-center">' + item.id + '</td>';
        html += '<td class="text-center">' + item.Name + '</td>';});
    $('#demoGrid tbody').html(html);
    $('#demoGrid').DataTable({}, error: function (error) {
    return error;
}
```